# Create YoY Graph with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am using IPython or the Python shell to interact with matplotlib. I have two `DataFrame`s.  Each has an index of months in the `'YYYY-MM'` format (these are just strings). The rest of the columns are sums of different values.

One `DataFrame` contains 2012 data, and the other contains 2013 data. Since it is still 2013, there are nulls for many of the 2013 months.

The graph I want to create just uses one metric at a time, and shows 2013 data as bars, and 2012 data as a line.  I want both graphs to be laid on top of each other, and share x- and y-axis. I also want the bars to be centered on each data point.

The nulls in the 2013 data seem to be causing issues.

Here is sample of what I have tried in IPython:

```
df2012['metric'].plot(color='black')
bar(np.arange(len(df2013.index)), df2013['metric'], align='center')
```

I have also tried using `twinx()` and `twiny()` but also having issues.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want?

Comment: What "null" values do you have? Are they actual float `NaN`s, or something different?

Comment: The nulls are actually NaNs.  Here is an example of the graph type I would like to make, mine would just share the y-axis as well.  http://www.sitelab.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/2010-ecommerce-spending-monthly-graph.jpg

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: You should define a function like the following because the limitation is that `matplotlib` doesn't allow you to share the y-axis when using `twinx` which is what it sounds like the problem might be:

```
from pandas.util.testing import makeTimeSeries as mkts

s = mkts()[:12].abs()
s2 = s[:7]

# align the series fill missing with nans
s, s2 = s.align(s2)

x = s.index.to_pydatetime()
y1 = s.values

bar(x, y1, align='center')


def mytwinx(ax, *args, **kwargs):
    ax2 = ax._make_twin_axes(*args, sharex=ax, frameon=False, **kwargs)
    ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
    ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
    ax2.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')
    ax.yaxis.tick_left()
    ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    return ax2

ax = gca()
ax2 = mytwinx(ax, sharey=ax)

y2 = s2.values
ax2.plot(x, y2, c='r', lw=2)
draw()
```

Here are two plots made with this code:

[image: nans at end part 1]
[image: nans at end part 2]

Comment: I'll open a github issue since passing `align` to the plot method doesn't do really do this...

Comment: What do you think `align` should do as an argument to `plot`?

Comment: @tcaswell Not `matplotlib.plot`. There's a `Series.plot` method that when you pass `kind='bar'` you essentially replicate `matplotlib.bar` and when `kind='line'` (the default) you get similar behavior to `matplotlib.plot`. The current behavior of `align` with `s.plot(kind='bar', align='center')` is a bit off. It seems to do the opposite of what `matplotlib.bar` does.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Understand now.

Comment: One of the issues I am having is that all of my NaNs are at the end of the 2013 values.  matplotlib wants to drop these from the graph by default which causes issues when trying to layer these plots on top of each other.  Your graphs only have NaNs in between the beginning and the end.  How would you handle graphing one Series that contains all 12 months of data, and another that only contains the first 7 months?

Comment: Rewrote my answer because I think your issue is that the y axis isn't shared when you call `twinx`. Looks like the only solution for now to make a hack using your own function. This might be worth reporting over at [`matplotlib`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)